# linux + cut file until specific word

Tags: perl, sed, awk, ksh

I have the file with the following format

How to cut the file until the line that start with number 2 ( not include line 2 )

before the new line with number 2 could be spaces or TABs ,

remark - implementation can be done with ksh or awk or sed or perl one liner etc

file:

```
* 0    

 Any text
 Any text
 .
 .

 1

 Any text
 Any text
 .
 .

 2

 Any text
 Any text
 .
 .

 3

 Any text
 Any text
 .
 .
```

Comment: Post some relevant input data and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pwe 'exit if $_ =~ /^\s*2/' file
```

This allows for any number of spaces between the start of the line and the number `2`

Answer (score 2):

You can "play" with a flag, that deactivates when the line is found:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=1} /^2/{f=0} f' file
```

`BEGIN{f=1}` initializes the flag as true. `/^2/{f=0}` unsets it when a line starts with `2`, `f`, when true, prints the line.

To also check lines having `2` after some spaces, you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=1} /\s*2/{f=0} f' file
```

Comment: pay attention - before number 0 or 1 I have the char "*" could be other char

Comment: @Eytan what do you mean? The only condition that is checked is the line starting with 2.

Comment: its mean that - number 0 in the begining of the line could be after some other char

Comment: @Eytan I still don't know what you mean. Do you want to print from the first line having `0`? What's the importance of `0` in your sample input?

Comment: the target is to print until the line that start with number 2 ( not include spaces or TAB ) because before number 2 could be spaces or TABs

Comment: @Eytan please provide some sample desired output. Also, do you mean column or line?

Comment: I mean new line the begin with number 2 ( but before number 2 could be spaces or tabs )

Comment: Now I understand. Then, can you check if this works to you? `awk 'BEGIN{f=1} /\s*2/{f=0} f' file`

Answer (score 2):

Just `exit` when you encounter the line you want to stop at:

```
awk '/[[:space:]]*2/{exit}1' file
```

Update: `[[:space:]]` will take care of spaces, tabs etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use sed to delete everything after (and including) the matching line

```
$ sed '/^[      ]*2/,$d' input.txt
```

That's a space and a tab in the character class.

Comment: `\s*` would work as well, thought I'd make it really obvious that it handles lines starting with WS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the instruction Q with sed so that it doesn't parse the rest of the file once it has found the appropriate end line:

```
sed '/^\s*2/Q' file
```